# sql query to find out most frequent item with provided item

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, data-mining

I am working on website in C# and I want to add recommendations. Since it is a basic level I want to give recommendations on most frequent item like market-basket analysis.

I want to build a query in which if I provided the name of one item (lets say `abc`) then it should return the name of an item which is repeating most or 50% (any one).

In short I just want to add feature like 'related in StackOverFlow'

Please Help.

Comment: In order to provide recommendations, you need to take one or more inputs, find data related to that input, then provide an output (your recommendations). I think you need to start by modelling the data you're trying to provide recommendations on.

Comment: lets say i have table with fields like order_id ,product_id,customer_id name and i want to get result like people who buy this also buy this and store it in database and then provide suggestion of related item with selected items . so what should i write in query ,@eclecticist and others

Comment: Have you written any code you can show us for this?

Comment: This is a huge and very difficult problem to solve properly. It's known an NP-Hard problem. Rob Connery has a great talk (and book) about how he tackled a problem like this and failed and got fired :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYlwiJ0vr_4

Comment: @pmcilreavy no, it is not np-hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your database layout.

You may need to use a nested query and group_by.

It's not going to be fast enough for the web, unless you precompute things, though or have very little data. You will also need indexes.